# Inserting Reverbnation Widget on site - using CSS to place it

Tags: html, css, widget, width

I've run into this problem before and couldn't figure it out, but it's basically just trying to insert two different embeds (youtube embed and a Reverbnation widget) and have them behave together.

I can get them to sit on top of each other... but when I insert them they take up the whole width of the page.  I know there's gotta be a way to limit the width of the widget right?

Here's the code for the page - real simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://static.tumblr.com/iorl8zv/yQxlnm3r2/favicon.png" />
<title>Official Pissing Graffiti--Rock-Industrial-Meaning</title>
<script type="text/javascript">


  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-24167987-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'pissinggraffiti.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowHash', 'false']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();


</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #666666; background-image: url('http://static.tumblr.com/iorl8zv/Me9ljgnyz/pgbgtumb.gif')">

<h1><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="180" height="150"><param name="movie" value="http://cache.reverbnation.com/widgets/swf/43/pro_widget.swf?id=artist_470177&posted_by=&skin_id=PWPS4008&font_color=FFFFFF"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><param name="allowNetworking" value="all"></param><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><param name="quality" value="best"></param><embed src="http://cache.reverbnation.com/widgets/swf/43/pro_widget.swf?id=artist_470177&posted_by=&skin_id=PWPS4008&font_color=FFFFFF" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowNetworking="all" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" quality="best" width="180" height="150"></embed></object><br/>
<img style="visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;" border=0 width=0 height=0 src="http://www.reverbnation.com/widgets/trk/43/artist_470177//t.gif" /></h1>
<div style="color: #ffb02e"><strong>
<center>New 8-track SAXAPHONE EP, by Pissing Graffiti</center></strong></div>
<div style="text-align: center">
<iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rn1SIXPZIgM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div><!--
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://music.pissinggraffiti.com"><img alt="" src="http://static.tumblr.com/iorl8zv/vIXlngmey/cover2.jpg" /></a></div-->
<div style="color: #ffb02d">
<center><font size="6">Free EP</font></center></div>
<div style="color: #ffb02e">
<center>Join the mailing list and immediately receive a link to a .zip file containing all 8 tracks with cover art and metadata.</center>
<center><br />
</center>
<center>
<div name="holder" style="border: 3px solid #FFB02E; width: 400px">
<div name="header" style="font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; padding-left: 4px; padding-top: 8px; text-align: left; color: #FFB02E!important; line-height: 12px">
      Join the mailing list</div>
<div style="text-align: center">
<form action="http://www.reverbnation.com/controller/fan_reach/add_email_direct/470177" target="_new" method="post"><span style="font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #fff !important">
          Email Address: </span><input name="email" type="text" style="width: 220px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Submit" style="font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 9px; color: #333 !important; background-color: #FFF !important" value="SUBMIT" type="submit" /><br />
<br /></form></div></div></center>
<div><a style="color: #ffb02e" "="" href="http://blog.pissinggraffiti.com"></a>
<center><a style="color: #ffb02e" "="" href="http://blog.pissinggraffiti.com">Head over to the blog.</a>or <a style="color: #ffb02e" href="http://blog.pissinggraffiti.com/socialize">See what we're all about.</a></center></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel like such an idiot when I post here because I can never figure out how to format the code so it looks readable.

I appreciate any help you can give.  I read through the W3 school tut and everytime I think I get it...i don't and my page disappears.

Thanks guys! have a blessed one!

Comment: Could you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or a link to the website that this happens on?

Comment: here's the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nmCT2/

I don't know what the stuff is at the top left, but I'm trying to get that 'quote' widget to be to the left of the youtube video.

Does that work? I hope I did that right.  Awesome site, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, you just want the quote widget to be in line with the YouTube video? In that case, refer to [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmCT2/1/). Basically all I did was set `embed`s, `object`s and `iframe`s to display inline (to stay in line with each other), got rid of the `<h1>` tag you had, since it's a block object, which would cause a line break, as well as deleted a `<br />` tag, and moved the quote widget above the YouTube video in the HTML.

Comment: thanks!! I'm going to read up on the how-to's of what you did.  But I have a question.  How can I edit the inline CSS so that the youtube video is still in the middle?  

Now, both the quote widget and the youtube imbed share the 'center' command.  Would I make two separate css entries?  one for the youtube video and then the other so I can place it better?

Comment: If you wanted to place the YouTube video in the middle, I would suggest wrapping it in a `<div>`, giving that `div` a class or id, and then using `position: absolute;` on the quote widget to position it to the left or the right side of the YouTube video. As it's late here, I can't make a demo of that right now, but once I'm back at the computer tomorrow, I can make a demo of what I mean here.

Comment: OK - I added this to the CSS section

Comment: OK - I added what I think appropriate to the CSS section giving the name #quote with some attributes.

Just don't know how to implement them in the body.  I tried to put them in div tags like this "<div id="#quote;">.....</div> but.. no luck.  If I put div tags around the widget it makes space for the whole page's width and they end up on top of each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/nmCT2/2/

Thank you very much for your help good sir.  It's really appreciated.

sorry, i timed out?

Comment: Ok, I cut the jsfiddle down to just the issue, since the rest of the markup was a little hard to get through, but here's the idea using `position: absolute`: http://jsfiddle.net/nmCT2/3/

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this!  I think it makes sense!

I can redesign the rest and get things tidy, but..just so I'm not crazy.  If I wanted to add a header image, I don't NEED to make it CSS right?

I can just go into <body> and enter

<center><p><img src="http://pissinggraffiti.com/images/pgheader.png></p></center>

yes?  for some reason the link works but in the page, when I preview it it's just a blue square =/

Comment: If you wanted to add a header image, that ought to work fine, as long as it is outside of other HTML tags.

Comment: ok, I think I've got it working.  Putting stuff in their right places.  Can't thank you enough =)

Answer (score 1):

CCS columns did the job for me! Just defined a #widgets div for the elements and tweaked their widths once they were in there. Don't forget the 'moz' and 'webkit' bits so it works on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

EMBED your Reverbnation songs using this code:

```
[gigya src="http://cache.reverbnation.com/widgets/swf/40/pro_widget.swf" 
    flashvars="id=artist_######&amp;posted_by=&amp;skin_id=PWAS1009&amp;
    font_color=12ff98&amp;auto_play=false&amp;shuffle=false" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always"
    allowNetworking="all" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" 
    quality="best" width="100%" height="300" ]
```

`REPLACE ######` in the `"id=artist_######&amp;"` segment with your own user id code which may be found at any of your personal song pages as seen in the location bar of your browser: `reverbnation.com/control_room/artist/######`

You can also change the style of your widget by changing the number after `"&amp;skin_id=PWAS"` to any number between `1000` and `1020`. Experiment to see what you get.